# Passing a variable through the form action

Tags: javascript, html, express

I wanted to be able to pass an id in the action of the form
example:
`action="/numeric id/prefix"`
precisely the numeric id must be a variable taken from the current url

I DON'T USE JQUERY

i try this:

```
<form id="prefix-form" method="post"  action="javascript:redictURL('prefix')">
                        <label for="prefix">Pre</label>
                        <hr></hr>
                        <input type="text" name="prefix" id="email" placeholder="&&prefix&&" required>
                        <input type="submit" value="" id="buttonPrefix">
                    </form>
```

the function "redictURL" take the url and add /prefix at the end:

```
const redictURL = (data) => {
                let id = location.pathname.split('/')[1]
                return `/${id}/${data}`
            }
```

,but what comes back to me in the end is [this](https://i.imgur.com/YX32jRd.png) and so it doesn't send a post request to the server like I would like

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) Note that the accepted answer’s original solution uses plain JavaScript. I recommend the first update above the original solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to set the `action` attribute of a form dynamically, you can do so in the `onsubmit` event:

```html
<form onsubmit="this.action = 'prefix'">
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

But if the `action` does not depend on the contents of the form, it would be better to have the server set the correct value directly when the form is rendered.